# Can I replicate these Cafe Noir cookies?

Tags: cookies

I recently bought a pack of [McVitie's Cafe Noir](http://www.waitrose.com/shop/ProductView-10317-10001-570-McVitie's+cafe+noir) expecting shop junk and for once quite liked it. It's very light and crunchy like a rich tea with a thin icing which seems to permeate the upper half (rather than a simple iced topping).

They seem to derive from the Dutch cookie "verkade cafe noir". I couldn't find a recipe or anyone trying to recreate them. Any ideas if they can be created at home?

Comment: Does your package have an ingredients list? The link you shared has nutritional information which gives some clues:  definitely includes flour and milk, has an incredibly high sugar to fat ratio (although some of the sugar might be part of the glaze you mention).  I have never heard of that specific cookie before - although they sound great and now I'm interested.  Also, out of curiosity, can you describe their texture more - are they more firm than, say, a shortbread cookie?  Maybe like a thicker airier graham cracker (the ratio of ingredients made me think of graham crackers)?

Comment: Here are the ingredients : Coffee Glaze (46%) [Sugar, Caramel, Coffee Powder (1%), Gelatine, Salt, Natural Flavourings], Wheat Flour, Sugar, Vegetable Oil, Glucose Syrup, Whey Solids, Raising Agents (Sodium Bicarbonate, Disodium Diphosphate), Salt, Natural Flavourings.

Comment: It's quite a plain biscuit. I was thinking, it's quite similar to a 'party ring' iced biscuit. It has a prominent snap and is quite airy and light. I'm not sure what a graham cracker tastes like (in the UK)